# Javascript focusin event not firing on HTML 5 date and time input elements

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, input

## EDIT: As of Chrome 39 this has been fixed. See [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408107)

I have a `focusin` listener on the parent element of each of my form elements. The listener is fired whenever I give focus to any field, but not when the new HTML 5 date and time inputs are focused by tabbing in or clicked on after tabbing in.

Listener Code:

```
app.directive('fctrl', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('focusin', function (event) {
                console.log(event.target)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Simplified layout:

```
<fctrl> <!--Angular Directive which I have attached the focus listener to -->
    <div>
        <!-- Omitted some divs -->
        <div class="field-holder">
            <input type="date" />
        </div>
        <!-- Omitted some divs -->
    </div>
</fctrl>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hb1x99m2/) demostrating the problem.

Is there a way to get the focusin event to fire on date/time elements?

Comment: This has nothing to do with AngularJS

Comment: At least in chrome, seems to work if I click on the date text, but not if I click on the border or in the / char, as if I were selecting text instead of focusing. Not sure how to fix it though

Comment: This sounds a bug of Chrome. You should report this on http://crbug.com/